# Inferring the numeric type (exact or inexact) of an array of strings?

Tags: python, numpy, parsing

Suppose I've got an array of strings and I know that they are numbers but don't know whether they are intish or floatish. If I knew, I could simply convert using `.astype(int)` or `.astype(float)`. What is a good (readable, performant, ideally not involving off the cuff regular expressions) way of finding out? Is there some Python or numpy machinery one could hijack?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could certainly do is parse them all as floats, since ints will also parse as floats. Then you can see if the remainder when divided by 1 is 0 ( if it is, then you have an integer). Then you have a boolean array telling you where the integers are. like so:

```py
import numpy as np
array = np.array(['454.13', '1.243', '8'])
floats = array.astype(float)
remainders = np.remainder(floats, 1)
int_indices = remainders == 0
ints = floats[int_indices]
```

I deliberately have done it here in 'too many' steps to make it clearer what I mean, hope this helps.

The output is:

```
>>>ints
array([8.00000000e+00])
>>>int_indices
array([False, False,  True])
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not safe. Try for example `x = 2**55-1` That's a perfectly good integer. Now, compare `int(float(x))` to `x`.

Comment: I have included the example in the edit. Try that. It seems that numpy handles conversions in a more robust manner :)

Comment: My point is you cannot losslessly store a large 64bit integer in a 53bit mantissa float.

Comment: Yes, you are right. You cannot do that in numpy since it has a constant memory space per every number in the array. In this case I can only think of rolling your own which is not what you wanted, I'm afraid I don't know how to help further, sorry.